# How to Implement the Search Bar in Objective-C via Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist, tableview, uisearchbar

I have this plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>City 1</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>area</key>
            <string>City 1</string>
            <key>shop</key>
            <string>Shop 1</string>
            <key>location</key>
            <string>Location 1</string>
            <key>coordinates</key>
            <string>14.66592, 121.03139</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>area</key>
            <string>City 1</string>
            <key>shop</key>
            <string>Shop 2</string>
            <key>location</key>
            <string>Location 2</string>
            <key>coordinates</key>
            <string>14.67097, 121.03766</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>City 2</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>area</key>
            <string>City 2</string>
            <key>shop</key>
            <string>Shop 1</string>
            <key>location</key>
            <string>Location 1</string>
            <key>coordinates</key>
            <string>14.65549, 120.98280</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>area</key>
            <string>City 2</string>
            <key>shop</key>
            <string>Shop 2</string>
            <key>location</key>
            <string>Location 2</string>
            <key>coordinates</key>
            <string>14.65549, 120.98280</string>
        </dict><dict>
            <key>area</key>
            <string>City 2</string>
            <key>shop</key>
            <string>Shop 3</string>
            <key>location</key>
            <string>Location 3</string>
            <key>coordinates</key>
            <string>14.65549, 120.98280</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

How can I implement a search bar in my table view where this is populated that has rows titled as the key "shop"? This is some code snippet on my search bar.

```
#pragma mark - Custom methods

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchText];
    self.searchResultsArray = [self.theArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

#pragma mark - SearchDisplayController methods
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text]
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:searchOption]];

    return YES;
}
```

I'm getting confused on how will I define my "theArray" array that the search bar will use to look for the shop names. I even tried to create another plist file that houses all of the shop names but it gives me an error:

> NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)

So I opted not to use that method and stick to my existing plist.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

SELF searches all the array, change it to shop.

NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"shop contains [cd] %@", searchText];